# I need to push data from various select statments to Azure SQL Database, best way to do so?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have some T-sql scripts which generate some data and we manually update them into the excel spreedsheet, we need a way to push this into azure sql database, from a job so that we can access them from there and remove the manual process of uploading the information to the azure sql database every time. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: when you say "from a job", is that an agent job on-premise? Where are you executing these tsql scripts?  Is that all done against on-premise databases?  If you have Integration Services on premise then a SSIS package can for sure handled that, on premise source to Azure database.  Linked server, as already mentioned in an answer.  Azure data sync is another option, but it sounds like there might be some complexity to these tsql scripts and won't be an easy on prem table to azure table sync.

Comment: I have data residing in azure sql database, I have various tsql commands that gives me data for a specific column, I need to insert this data in order database in each of the columns, the job will run on each month moving data to another table on different table using column by column. Any way this can be achived?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to move data from an on prem server to Azure.  The simplest method may be [Azure Data Sync](http://I%20assume%20you%20are%20trying%20to%20move%20data%20from%20an%20on%20prem%20server%20to%20Azure.%20%20The%20simplest%20method%20may%20be%20using%20Azure%20DataSync.).

You could load your data from your queries into an on prem table which syncs to Azure.

Comment: I am not moving data from onpremise to azure, I have data residing in azure sql database, I have various tsql commands that gives me data for a specific column, I need to insert this data in order database in each of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

On all your SQL Server instances, you can create a Linked Server to one Azure SQL Database. Once the linked server is created you can directly insert on Azure SQL Database from your on-premises SQL Server instances.

Here is how you create the Linked Server.

[image]

Below image shows how you insert data on Azure SQL Database using the linked server.

[image]

For detailed steps, you can visit [this](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0016.htm) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can think about Azure Data Factory.

Azure Data Factory Copy Active can help you use T-sql scripts to move data to another Azure SQL database.
[image]

For more details, please the Azure tutorial:[Copy multiple tables in bulk by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-bulk-copy-portal).

When the pipeline created, you can trigger and monitor the pipeline runs.

**Trigger the pipeline on a schedule**:

You can create a scheduler trigger to schedule the pipeline to run periodically (hourly, daily, and so on). In this procedure, you create a trigger to run every minute until the end date and time that you specify.

[image]

Please see: [Trigger the pipeline on a schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-portal#trigger-the-pipeline-on-a-schedule). 
This can help you push the data to Azure SQL Database automatically.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have mutiple tsql statments that needs to be stored in multiple columns in a specific table, how can I achive this one? also I want to create tables as per each month with the same TSQL commands.

Comment: Hi @user0001ttt, you mean you want  the T-SQL statement  stored in the specific table columns? Or you want to insert the data which your muliple T-SQL statements  get into the specific table columns? They are different. For first one, Azure SQL database supports nvarchar() datatype, it's similar to String. For second, you can use the Data Factory Source settings, set Table Query,input your T-SQL,  query out all the data you want to insert to the specific table. Then just  follow the tutorial. I think you can achieve your purpose. If my answer helps you, can you please accpet it? Thanks.

Comment: So let me get in depth, I have 8 columns that are related to specific T-SQL statments ok, I have created each one of them columns in my Azure SQL Database, for now I am using SSIS Packages a data movement task to move the data now I can pass 1 TSQL statement and map that to 1 sepcific column, but when I create another data task for 2nd column and execute the data task, what happend is I see NULLS on all the rows of first set of columns, is there any way I can remove the nulls? Can we do a skype meeting so that I can explain you my issue in depth?

Comment: You mean the task you create just effected one column?For now, I suggest you can post another blog, show us some of your  T-SQL statements,  what you have done, the error message or images ,etc. We need to know more details, then I and others can give you more supports.

Answer (score -1):

you can try the SSIS package? which automates the process of data upload data into azure sql database....  i have not used ssis for Azure but to sink data from csv/xls/xlsx into ms sql server database,,[I  refered this article which can be helpful in anyway](https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2018/01/azure-ssis-how-to-setup-deploy-execute-schedule-packages/)

Comment: Thanks for the update user3667576, but we are not going to upload the data into excel spreedsheet, we direclty want to upload the data into the azrue sql database from the tsql queries which generates different columns.